# Do you get notifications during suspension?

Tags: support, notifications, account-suspension

When a user is suspended, they cannot do any action on the site where they were suspended. (Or on any site, in the case of networkwide suspension.) Still, they can visit the site and they can log in.

**Question:** Does the suspended user still get notification into the inbox? Do they work in the same way as for an account that is not suspended?